# How interchangeable are the terms "error", " err" and "Error" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm learning JS and it seems there is a degree of interchange with the syntax variations for error handling. My impression is that consistency within the scope seems to be important then obviously fix syntax/undefined errors reported in the console, but is there an established set of rules as to when and where to use the terms "error" "err" and "Error"?

Comment: From a conversational standpoint, there is no difference - - use what you like. When it comes to syntax, JavaScript is case-sensitive and that is not up for debate.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're referring to? If you mean things like the parameters to callback functions, you can name them whatever you want.

Comment: `Error` is a built in class in javascript, you can use it to construct custom error objects. I would never use `Error` as a variable name. On the other hand, `err` is the conventional name for the first parameter of a [node style callback](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/), and by extension is used as the variable name for most error values.

Comment: @CRice JavaScript doesn't have classes. It has Objects and Prototypes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus [That's incorrect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes), but you're right to point out that `Error` is an Object rather than a class.

Comment: @zcoop98 [Sigh] Did you actually read the link you shared? Classes are syntactical sugar. They aren't actual constructs. `class` is syntax, not a real "thing". Nothing in JavaScript is a class. It's all objects.

Comment: I'm not gonna argue with you. A ton of modern Javascript *is* syntactic sugar, and whether something is or isn't a "thing" based on whether it's syntactic sugar or not is a debate all on it's own.

Comment: @Barmar  conditional statements would probably be the main ones that I have come across

Comment: @zcoop98 I'm not going to argue with you either, because this is not something that is up for debate. JavaScript doesn't have classes. You misunderstood me to mean syntax, when the comment and my reply to it were clearly referring to an OOP construct.

Comment: @zcoop98 *and whether something is or isn't a "thing" based on whether it's syntactic sugar or not is a debate all on it's own.* <-- No, it's really not. If it can be constructed in memory, it's a thing. If it's syntax, it's.. well..just syntax.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Throughout that document it refers to classes as things. As in "one way to define a class is..." If it walks like a duck....

Comment: @MaxPietrzak Can you update the question and show examples of the code you're concerned with?

Comment: @Barmar I think you are being contrarian now. ;) The first paragraph of the article states *JavaScript classes, introduced in ECMAScript 2015, are primarily syntactical sugar over JavaScript's existing prototype-based inheritance. The class syntax does not introduce a new object-oriented inheritance model to JavaScript.* and goes on to say *Classes are in fact "special functions"*. You and I both know JavaScript doesn't have actual classes. A `class` keyword yes, `classes`, no.

Comment: @ScottMarcus And then the rest of the document goes on to treat classes as a thing. When you use this syntactic sugar, you can program as if JS really has classes.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, that's true and I didn't say otherwise. They are a magic trick to make coding OOP simple for those who come from classical OOP languages. But, there is not lower level `class` construct. It's funny that you end by saying *you can program as if JS really has classes*, which is an acknowledgement that JS really **doesn't** have them.

Comment: @ScottMarcus True. But like I said, "if it walks like a duck". You can consider `Error` to be a class because you can use it like one.

Comment: @Barmar I probably could but have time constraints and don't think it's necessary as the issue looks pervasive rather than isolated and reasonably easily handled. If someone could post a concise answer to the question for the JS environment that would be appreciated.

Comment: @MaxPietrzak Without examples, it's really hard to understand your question. Questions about programming style, such as variable naming, are off-topic here.

Comment: @Barmar I wouldn't agree with your statement there, it reads like an easy out. We are talking basic error handling and they are the 3 common variants which appear somewhat interchangeable in js from my experience thus far. The errors themselves arising from their misuse is easy enough to handle but the question remains and is reasonably straight forward. The comments read like you are avoiding the question.